# Retaining Tab controls data in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a multiple tabs and I am calling an ascx file for each tab, I have some control and submit button for each ascx file. Now I when ever I enter the data in first tab and switch to second tab and enter some data and click on submit then the first tab data is also getting empty.

I want to keep the data for the first tab or when I enter data on the firrst tab and click submit then what ever the data is there in other tabs must be there.

Can any one some source how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

MVC2 has no "viewstate" like web.forms does. That means if it's not on the screen in some way, you must store it in session to persist it. I wouldn't recomend using session as you can tie youreself in knots in some situations, but can be appropriate for some things.

You basically have 2 options left if you don't want to use session:

1 - Show your tabs all on 1 page and then show/hide them using jquery to the client

For example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showTab('tabcontents1');">Tab 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="showTab('tabcontents2');">Tab 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="showTab('tabcontents3');">Tab 3</a>

<div id="tabcontents1" class="tabcont">
...
</div>
<div id="tabcontents2" class="tabcont">
...
</div>
<div id="tabcontents3" class="tabcont">
...
</div>
```

Then use JQuery or javascript to hide them on load and show them on click. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".tabcont").hide();
});

function showTab(tab) {
   $(".tabcont").hide();
   $("#"+tab).show();
}
```

OR

2 - Put any data you want to persist in hidden inputs on your form. If you only have a small model, this can be the easiest approach.

**NOTE:** This rule is a HTML rule, not an MVC rule. Webforms just "fakes" persistance with ViewState and MVC is more honest about how you deal with http.